# Horizontal scrolling won't activate for ttk Treeview widget

Tags: python-2.7, treeview, tkinter, scrollbar, ttk

I'm using the ttk Treeview widget to implement a folder/path selection dialog.  It's all working as expected except that my horizontal scrollbar won't activate.  No matter how wide the folder path goes horizontally, and no matter how narrow the window, the horizontal slider never appears.  Vertical scrolling is working perfectly though.

I'm figuring it's either some kind of limitation when you only use one column in the treeview, or just a newbie mistake with configuring and connecting the widgets.  I'd bet on the latter.

Example with dialog widened to show full folder depth:

[image: full width]

Dialog narrowed to the point where horizontal scrolling should activate (but doesn't):

[image: narrowed width]

Here's my GUI layout code:

```
winDirSel = tk.Toplevel()
winDirSel.title('Select Test Directory...')
tvwDirSel = ttk.Treeview(winDirSel,
                         height=10,padding=3,
                         show='tree')
lblTestDir = tk.Label(winDirSel, relief=tk.SUNKEN,
                      justify=tk.LEFT, anchor=tk.W,
                      textvariable=ctrlTestDir,width=80)
scbHDirSel = ttk.Scrollbar(winDirSel,
                           orient=tk.HORIZONTAL,
                           command=tvwDirSel.xview)
scbVDirSel = ttk.Scrollbar(winDirSel,
                           orient=tk.VERTICAL,
                           command=tvwDirSel.yview)
tvwDirSel.configure(xscrollcommand=scbHDirSel.set,
                    yscrollcommand=scbVDirSel.set)
lblTestDir.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=tk.EW)
tvwDirSel.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=tk.NSEW)
scbVDirSel.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky=tk.NS)
scbHDirSel.grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=tk.EW)
winDirSel.rowconfigure(1,weight=1)
winDirSel.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
```

Comment: It doesn't fully work across platforms, indeed. What you can do is setting a `minwidth` parameter per column, as well as playing with `stretch=False`. It is buggy in this regard.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

OK, after some playing with `minwidth` and `stretch`, I think I have a better handle on it.  The horizontal scrolling is triggered by the **column-edge** going out of the window's bounds, not the content of the column.  So you can use these parameters to force the column to be wider and thus force the scrolling.

The problem though is that you then lose the automatic adjustment of the column width to suit the width of the tree itself.  You either have to force it very wide to accommodate any (assumed) likely folder depth, or you live with folder names getting truncated at the right boundary of the column.

So bottom line:  it's just a limitation of the widget itself.  (At least with respect to its behavior on my platform, MS Windows.)

Comment: One trick I discovered is for each column that you want to allow to grow beyond the right-edge of the viewable area, set its `width` property to either a default width or `0`, and then set `minwidth` to the width you actually want. `stretch` must also be set to `True`. This will cause the column to stretch beyond the viewable area, activating the horizontal scrollbar. If you try setting just `width`, you'll only make the widget grow wider.

Comment: @Kumba: thx for this great comment! It would've never occurred to me that setting `minwidth` as larger than `width` would be a sane idea let alone do the trick :). In my case though it was a bit different. I sticked to your advice to let `minwidth` be the desired column widths and set `stretch` to `True` for all columns, but gave each column the same `width` of value that together added up to the desire width of my treeview widget.

Comment: I finally drafted a [lengthy question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49715456/) about a particular scenario of Treeview's issues w/ horizontal scrolling.  It is possible to cause the widget to shrink back after expanding, but in my situation, not pretty.  The trick is to invoke the internal `TtkResizeWidget()` function, either by generating the hidden `<<ThemeChanged>>` virtual event, or calling `grid_remove()` before changing the column widths, then `grid()` after (if using the grid geom manager).

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I finally came up with to display a `TreeView` of files which are lazy-loaded (thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16748186/253127)) which is inside a `PanedWindow` (SplitterWindow in wxPython terms) along with a `Notebook`. The scrollbars are auto-displayed/hidden as needed, thanks to [this example](http://svn.python.org/projects/stackless/trunk/Demo/tkinter/ttk/dirbrowser.py).

```
import os
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk as ttk
from ScrolledText import ScrolledText

class App(object):
    def __init__(self, master, path):
        splitter = tk.PanedWindow(master, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL)
        # left-side
        frame_left = tk.Frame(splitter)
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(frame_left, show='tree')
        ysb = ttk.Scrollbar(frame_left, orient='vertical', command=self.tree.yview)
        xsb = ttk.Scrollbar(frame_left, orient='horizontal', command=self.tree.xview)
        # right-side
        frame_right = tk.Frame(splitter)
        nb = ttk.Notebook(frame_right)
        page1 = ttk.Frame(nb)
        page2 = ttk.Frame(nb)
        text = ScrolledText(page2)

        # overall layout
        splitter.add(frame_left)
        splitter.add(frame_right)
        splitter.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
        # left-side widget layout
        self.tree.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='NSEW')
        ysb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
        xsb.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='ew')
        # left-side frame's grid config
        frame_left.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        frame_left.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        # right-side widget layout
        text.pack(expand=1, fill="both")
        nb.add(page1, text='One')
        nb.add(page2, text='Two')
        nb.pack(expand=1, fill="both")

        # setup
        self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand=lambda f, l:self.autoscroll(ysb,f,l), xscrollcommand=lambda f, l:self.autoscroll(xsb,f,l))
        # use this line instead of the previous, if you want the scroll bars to always be present, but grey-out when uneeded instead of disappearing
        #self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand=ysb.set, xscrollcommand=xsb.set)
        self.tree.heading('#0', text='Project tree', anchor='w')
        self.tree.column("#0",minwidth=1080, stretch=True)
        # add default tree node
        abspath = os.path.abspath(path)
        self.nodes = dict()
        self.insert_node('', abspath, abspath)
        self.tree.bind('<<TreeviewOpen>>', self.open_node)

    def autoscroll(self, sbar, first, last):
        """Hide and show scrollbar as needed."""
        first, last = float(first), float(last)
        if first <= 0 and last >= 1:
            sbar.grid_remove()
        else:
            sbar.grid()
        sbar.set(first, last)

    def insert_node(self, parent, text, abspath):
        node = self.tree.insert(parent, 'end', text=text, open=False)
        if os.path.isdir(abspath):
            self.nodes[node] = abspath
            self.tree.insert(node, 'end')

    def open_node(self, event):
        node = self.tree.focus()
        abspath = self.nodes.pop(node, None)
        if abspath:
            self.tree.delete(self.tree.get_children(node))
            for p in os.listdir(abspath):
                self.insert_node(node, p, os.path.join(abspath, p))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("800x600")
    app = App(root, path='.')
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import tkinter.font as tk_font

class TreeListBox:

    def __init__(self, master, root, dict_group):
        self.master = master
        self.root = root
        self.dict_group = dict_group
        self.level = 0
        self.setup_widget_tree()
        self.build_tree(self.root, '')

    def setup_widget_tree(self):
        container_tree = tk.Frame(self.master, width=250, height=300)
        container_tree.propagate(False)
        container_tree.pack(side="left", fill='y')
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(container_tree, show="tree", selectmode='browse')
        fr_y = tk.Frame(container_tree)
        fr_y.pack(side='right', fill='y')
        tk.Label(fr_y, borderwidth=1, relief='raised', font="Arial 8").pack(side='bottom', fill='x')
        sb_y = tk.Scrollbar(fr_y, orient="vertical", command=self.tree.yview)
        sb_y.pack(expand='yes', fill='y')
        fr_x = tk.Frame(container_tree)
        fr_x.pack(side='bottom', fill='x')
        sb_x = tk.Scrollbar(fr_x, orient="horizontal", command=self.tree.xview)
        sb_x.pack(expand='yes', fill='x')
        self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand=sb_y.set, xscrollcommand=sb_x.set)
        self.tree.pack(fill='both', expand='yes')

    def build_tree(self, parent, id_stroki):
        self.level += 1
        id = self.tree.insert(id_stroki, 'end', text=parent)
        # -----------------
        col_w = tk_font.Font().measure(parent)
        if col_w > 1000:
            col_w -= 400
        elif col_w > 500:
            col_w -= 200
        elif col_w > 300:
            col_w -= 100
        col_w = col_w + 25 * self.level
        if col_w > self.tree.column('#0', 'width'):
            self.tree.column('#0', width=col_w)
        # -----------------
        for element in sorted(self.dict_group[parent]):
            self.build_tree(element, id)
        self.level -= 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dict_group = {'Nomenclature': ['ABC1', 'ABC2'],
                  'ABC1': ['ABC3', 'ABC4'],
                  'ABC2': ['ABC5'],
                  'ABC3': ['ABC______________________________________6'],
                  'ABC4': ['ABC--------------------------------------8'],
                  'ABC5': ['ABC######################################9'],
                  'ABC______________________________________6': [],
                  'ABC--------------------------------------8': [],
                  'ABC######################################9': []
                  }
    root = tk.Tk()
    myTest = TreeListBox(root, 'Nomenclature', dict_group)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't fully address the question.  It yields an initial "automatic" adjustment of the width based on the initial content of the tree (which is a nice feature, and cleverly done).  But it still lacks the ability I was looking for, to stretch and shrink the window while having the scrolling activate and deactivate accordingly.