# Display directory content with tkinter Treeview widget

Tags: python, treeview, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I am working on a program that has its own project files and inside that are like sub-files and I want to know how to use the treeview widget to display all the sub-files inside the project file, Any Ideas?

Comment: The imports can be changed at the second and third lines supporting Python 3.4 and above in the following manner: import tkinter as tk import tkinter.ttk as ttk *Lowercase t in tkinter replacing capital T in Tkinter because Python 3.4 and above no longer recognize Tkinter; eliminates an "unrecognized reference" error.* Fully qualified import directives in newer Python releases are more strict about dot notation all around, therefore tkinter.ttk as ttk is required and eliminates the need for repetitive fully qualified references. Caveat: one would assume that import tk.ttk would suffice, but so

Comment: This opensource project might help you a lot: https://github.com/talcs/tals_python_task_diary

Answer (score 30):

There is an [example in the source code of CPython](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/f4981d8eb401/Demo/tkinter/ttk/dirbrowser.py) of how to fill a Treeview recursively with the content of a directory, this is basically how it works (I have removed the event bindings and wrapped it in a class for better readability):

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, path):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self)
        ysb = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient='vertical', command=self.tree.yview)
        xsb = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient='horizontal', command=self.tree.xview)
        self.tree.configure(yscroll=ysb.set, xscroll=xsb.set)
        self.tree.heading('#0', text=path, anchor='w')

        abspath = os.path.abspath(path)
        root_node = self.tree.insert('', 'end', text=abspath, open=True)
        self.process_directory(root_node, abspath)

        self.tree.grid(row=0, column=0)
        ysb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
        xsb.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='ew')
        self.grid()

    def process_directory(self, parent, path):
        for p in os.listdir(path):
            abspath = os.path.join(path, p)
            isdir = os.path.isdir(abspath)
            oid = self.tree.insert(parent, 'end', text=p, open=False)
            if isdir:
                self.process_directory(oid, abspath)

root = tk.Tk()
path_to_my_project = # ...
app = App(root, path=path_to_my_project)
app.mainloop()
```

---

**Update:** As @ArtOfWarfare mentions, it is possible to lazy populate the tree using the `<<TreeviewOpen>>` event. To simulate the closed nodes, I've used an empty child item that is removed when a directory is opened:

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


class App(object):
    def __init__(self, master, path):
        self.nodes = dict()
        frame = tk.Frame(master)
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(frame)
        ysb = ttk.Scrollbar(frame, orient='vertical', command=self.tree.yview)
        xsb = ttk.Scrollbar(frame, orient='horizontal', command=self.tree.xview)
        self.tree.configure(yscroll=ysb.set, xscroll=xsb.set)
        self.tree.heading('#0', text='Project tree', anchor='w')

        self.tree.grid()
        ysb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
        xsb.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='ew')
        frame.grid()

        abspath = os.path.abspath(path)
        self.insert_node('', abspath, abspath)
        self.tree.bind('<<TreeviewOpen>>', self.open_node)

    def insert_node(self, parent, text, abspath):
        node = self.tree.insert(parent, 'end', text=text, open=False)
        if os.path.isdir(abspath):
            self.nodes[node] = abspath
            self.tree.insert(node, 'end')

    def open_node(self, event):
        node = self.tree.focus()
        abspath = self.nodes.pop(node, None)
        if abspath:
            self.tree.delete(self.tree.get_children(node))
            for p in os.listdir(abspath):
                self.insert_node(node, p, os.path.join(abspath, p))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root, path='.')
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Assuming that the questioner was really doing mapping of the filesystem, that's a good solution.

Comment: @DonalFellows - This is a good answer no matter what the questioner was really trying to do, because it really answers what they asks. It's exactly what I wanted (an example of Treeview - I'm just getting started with tk/ttk and need to see some more examples before I'm ready to write stuff from scratch on my own.)

Comment: Over two years later, I have a different thought on this - won't it be really inefficient? You're going to populate directories the user may never end up expanding. Surely there's a way to defer calling `process_directory` until the user actually opens it?

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare Sure it's possible, see my updated answer. If the directory tree is large, the lazy load may be a better solution - however, the example gets a little more complex IMO.

Comment: Great. But its not horizontally scrollable. Sub directories are overflowed from the treeview.