# python tkinter - Make a treeview widget for Directory display with a list of folders

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

so what i want to say is that i want a tkinter treeview widget which shows all files and sub-folders in the directory..
and that too with viewing folders from a list of folders..

I have till now tried that by making a treeview for a single directory but can't make it to view a list of directories

Comment: you may need to use recursion to run the same code for subfolder. OR you can use `os.walk()` to work with all subfolders.

Comment: if you have list then use `for`-loop to repeate it for every folder on list.

Comment: better show minimal working code - it will be simpler to create solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16746387/display-directory-content-with-tkinter-treeview-widget)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't show code so I don't understand what is your problem.

If you have `list` then use `for`-loop.

---

Minimal working code for list with two folders `['test', 'Pobrane']`

I use `listdir()` but you may need `os.walk()`

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

folders = ['test', 'Pobrane']

root = tk.Tk()

tree = ttk.Treeview()
tree.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

for folder in folders:
    tree.insert('', 'end', folder, text=folder)
    for name in os.listdir(folder):
        tree.insert(folder, 'end', name, text=name)
        
root.mainloop()
```

[image]