# Horizontal scrollbar doesn´t work in a kind of table in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, tkinter-entry, ttk

I am trying to create a table using tkinter for python:

I have the next code:

```
from tkinter import *
from  tkinter import ttk

ws  = Tk()
ws.title('PythonGuides')
ws.geometry('500x500')
ws['bg'] = 'Black'

game_frame = Frame(ws)
game_frame.pack()

game_scroll = Scrollbar(game_frame, orient='vertical')
game_scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

game_scroll = Scrollbar(game_frame,orient='horizontal')
game_scroll.pack(side= BOTTOM,fill=X)

my_game = ttk.Treeview(game_frame,yscrollcommand=game_scroll.set, xscrollcommand =game_scroll.set)

my_game.pack()

game_scroll.config(command=my_game.yview)
game_scroll.config(command=my_game.xview)

my_game['columns'] = ('_id', '_name')

my_game.column("#0", width=0,  stretch=NO)
my_game.column("_id",anchor=CENTER, width=80)
my_game.column("_name",anchor=CENTER,width=80)

my_game.heading("#0",text="",anchor=CENTER)
my_game.heading("_id",text="Id",anchor=CENTER)
my_game.heading("_name",text="Step",anchor=CENTER)

#add data 
for i in range(40):
    my_game.insert(parent='',index='end',iid=i,text='',values=(str(i + 1),'Going to the step '+str(i + 1)))
my_game.pack()
ws.mainloop()
```

Pricipal problem is that horizontal scrollbar doesn´t work, so I am not able to see in what step is it going.

It only looks like this:

[image: first image]

I am just able to move down or up, but I am not able to move at left or right.
So I hope someone can help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is a link that explains how to connect `Scrollbar` vertical and horizontal. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14359906/horizontal-scrolling-wont-activate-for-ttk-treeview-widget

Comment: In order to get the horizontal scrollbar working properly it's necessary to include `minwidth` in `my_game.column(`. I've modified my answer to include that. So now both scrollbars work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have vertical and horizontal scrollbars with the same name.
Try changing code along the lines of the following snippet.

```py
game_scrollV = Scrollbar(game_frame, orient='vertical')
game_scrollV.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

game_scrollH = Scrollbar(game_frame,orient='horizontal')
game_scrollH.pack(side= BOTTOM,fill=X)

my_game = ttk.Treeview(
    game_frame,
    yscrollcommand = game_scrollV.set,
    xscrollcommand = game_scrollH.set)

my_game.pack()

game_scrollV.config(command=my_game.yview)
game_scrollH.config(command=my_game.xview)

my_game.column("_id",anchor=CENTER, minwidth = 100, width=80)
my_game.column("_name",anchor=CENTER,minwidth = 100, width=80)
```